# HttpWebRequest fails from MVC application

Tags: model-view-controller, httpwebrequest

I need to get a http directory listing of an external web site from within my MVC app.

The following works fine in a console app:

```
string url = "http://nemweb.com.au/Reports/Current/TradingIS_Reports/";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But returns ""The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable." when run from an MVC application in Visual Studio debug on my PC.

I'm using identity impersonation in the MVC app.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do this request success in client(insomnia), and the req-res timeline as following:

```
> GET /Reports/Current/TradingIS_Reports/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: nemweb.com.au
> User-Agent: insomnia/6.0.2
> Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.nemweb.com.au
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Thu, 13 Sep 2018 06:38:57 GMT
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< Content-Length: 138681
< Connection: keep-alive
```

It seems not the server restricts. Does it a fortuitous failure?

Comment: Thanks XXLive. I also get a good response from a web browser and from the same code in a console application, but it fails from MVC. I looked further and found the response was returning:
Web Page Blocked
Access to the web page you were trying to visit has been blocked in accordance with company policy. Please contact your system administrator if you believe this is in error.
Category: Custom - Wildcard ALL

Looks like an internal policy from a firewall or web nanny?